# How do you get more items returned than the default RSS item count or is this even possible?

Tags: wordpress, count, rss

I am writing a program to consolidate data from multiple blogs via RSS feeds.  My intent is get to get all the items in the RSS feeds that are newer than the last time I ran the program (about once a week), and then generate one consolidated webpage with just the new information.  Is it possible to do this?

As a point of reference, I am starting with https://blogs.windows.com/feed, which is the RSS feed for https://blogs.windows.com.  As I write this on November 17, I see items on the page going back to November 4 for a total of 16 items.  In the RSS feed, there are only 10 items.

Is there a way to increase the number of items returned or to get additional "pages" worth of a feed?  I believe these feeds are generated by Wordpress and I do not see any documentation for Wordpress that indicates you can get anything besides the default item count.

Comment: the number of posts shown can be set in admin -> Settings -> Reading

Comment: The RSS feed is being downloaded from a console app.  There are no settings.  Either I need query parameters or something to put in the body of the http request.